# `Checkpoint` was expecting a trackable object (an object derived from `TrackableBase`), got name: "Adam_1"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using TensorFlow 1.14 to create a GAN model, but I get the following error

```
ValueError: `Checkpoint` was expecting a trackable object (an object derived from `TrackableBase`), got name: "Adam_1"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv1/AssignMovingAvg"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv1/AssignMovingAvg_1"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv2/AssignMovingAvg"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv2/AssignMovingAvg_1"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv3/AssignMovingAvg"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv3/AssignMovingAvg_1"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv4/AssignMovingAvg"
input: "^generator/batch_trans_conv4/AssignMovingAvg_1"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/dense/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/dense/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv1/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv1/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv1/gamma/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv1/beta/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv2/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv2/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv2/gamma/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv2/beta/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv3/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv3/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv3/gamma/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv3/beta/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv4/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/trans_conv4/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv4/gamma/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/batch_trans_conv4/beta/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/logits/kernel/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/update_generator/logits/bias/ApplyAdam"
input: "^Adam_1/Assign"
input: "^Adam_1/Assign_1"
```

I am using the AdamOptimizer and checkpointing the generator optimizer and discriminator optimizer using the following code

```
LR_D = 0.00004
LR_G = 0.0004
BETA1 = 0.5

d_train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR_D, beta1=BETA1)
g_train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LR_G, beta1=BETA1)  
checkpoint_dir = 'training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt") 

checkpoint =  tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=g_train_opt, discriminator_optimizer=d_train_opt)
```

**How to save the AdamOptimizer values using checkpoints?**